# Change Spring logging format

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, log4j

Trying to change logging format in simple Hello World `Spring` application taken from [quick start](https://spring.io/quickstart) .

I just have placed `log4j.properties` file with content below in projects `/src/main/resources`

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, consoleAppender, fileAppender
 
log4j.appender.consoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
 
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=demoApplication.log
```

But logging not changed after running `./gradlew bootRun`. How to change logging in Spring project?

Comment: where are you checking logs.? 
you link example results hello worlds as response

Comment: I'm expecting change log format in console, but I also can't find `demoApplication.log` in project directory

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **logback-spring.xml** where you can specify log pattern based on profiles or if you are using spring boot you can add default logging pattern in application.properties

> logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n